# Receiving a char* from c++ into c#, and passing it back again

Tags: c#, c++, char, marshalling

I'm having memory leak issues with a third party c++ dll.  For certain calls, the dll allocates memory for the string, passes it out as a char* and then expects to receive that pointer back so that it can de-allocate the memory.

Here are some comments from the header file, a couple of examples of where the char* get returned, and the signature of the "Release" method.

(The dll is called SW_API, it's from a trade clearing house - if anyone has perhaps wrapped this already I'd love to talk to them!).

```
   /* Strings returned by the API are similarly normal nul-terminated C strings.
   * The user should not attempt to change any of the bytes or read past the
   * terminating nul of any returned string. All returned strings must be
   * released using SW_ReleaseString() once the user is finished with the
   * result. Failure to do this will result in memory leaks.
   */

    /**
     * @typedef const char* SW_XML
     * @brief A string containing an XML documents text.
     * @note As with all output strings, returned XML must be freed
     * by the user. See @ref resource.
     * @sa ErrorCodes
     */
    typedef const char* SW_XML;

    const char* STDAPICALLTYPE SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics();

    SW_ErrCode STDAPICALLTYPE SW_DealGetSWML(SW_LoginID           lh,
                                     const char*          swmlVersion,
                                     SW_DealVersionHandle dealVersionHandle,
                                     SW_XML*              resultXML_out);


    void STDAPICALLTYPE SW_ReleaseString(const char* buffer);
```

Attempting to read up from various sources, I have tried the following:

```
    // Extern declarations
    [DllImport(sw_api_dll, EntryPoint = "_SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics@0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics();

    [DllImport(sw_api_dll, EntryPoint = "_SW_DealGetSWML@16", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int SW_DealGetSWML(int lh, string swmlVersion, string dealVersionHandle, [Out] out IntPtr outputSWML);

    [DllImport(sw_api_dll, EntryPoint = "_SW_ReleaseString@4", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void SW_ReleaseString(IntPtr buffer);


    // Using the externs.
    private static string GetIntPtrStringAndRelease(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        API.SW_ReleaseString(ptr);
        return result;
    }

    public static int SW_DealGetSWML(int lh, string swmlVersion, string dealVersionHandle, ref string outputSWML)
    {
        IntPtr outputSWML_out = new IntPtr();
        int result = API.SW_DealGetSWML(lh, swmlVersion, dealVersionHandle, out outputSWML_out);

        outputSWML = GetIntPtrStringAndRelease(outputSWML_out);

        return result;
    }

    public static string SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = API.SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics();
        return GetIntPtrStringAndRelease(ptr);
    }
```

It seems I just can't get the API to release the strings.

Now, it's possible that this is just a bug in the API, but I doubt it.
More likely is I'm doing something funamentally wrong.

All I know is that my working set just keeps on growing.

The company in question provide a Java wrapper but won't stretch to a .Net wrapper.

Any help most gratefully received.

Brett.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the API to me. If the data you're getting back (i.e. the value returned from `GetIntPtrStringAndRelease` is good), then this should work.

Comment: `GetIntPtrStringAndRelease` looks good to me.

Comment: The value I get back is good.  I almost wish it wasn't!

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the IntPtr is not equivalent to the char* of your string.  So when you call SW_ReleaseString, you're not providing the same pointer.

What you can do, is throw together a little C++CLI intermediary.  In C++CLI, and you will have access to the `char*` directly, as well as being able to use Marshal::PtrToString and managed string pointers, with `String^`.

Here's what I think that would look like:

C++/CLI:

```
String^ GetStringAndRelease(char* ptr)
{
    string result = Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    SW_ReleaseString(ptr);
    return result;
}

int SW_DealGetSWML(int lh, const char* swmlVersion, const char* dealVersionHandle, String% outputSWML)
{
    char* outputSWML_out;
    int result = SW_DealGetSWML(lh, swmlVersion, dealVersionHandle, outputSWML_out);

    outputSWML = GetStringAndRelease(outputSWML_out);

    return result;
}

String^ SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics()
{
    char* ptr = SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics();
    return GetStringAndRelease(ptr);
}
```

and then in C#:

```
[DllImport(your_wrapper_dll, EntryPoint = "_SW_DealGetSWML@16", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int SW_DealGetSWML(int lh, string swmlVersion, string dealVersionHandle, [Out] out string outputSWML);


[DllImport(your_wrapper_dll, EntryPoint = "_SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics@0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string SW_GetLastErrorSpecifics();
```

Comment: If you're making a C++/CLI DLL, you don't need to DllImport. It's a full-fledged .NET assembly, you'd add a reference to it in the same way you'd add a reference to an external C# assembly, no DllImports needed. (C# `ref string` would turn into C++/CLI `String^%`, BTW.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @David!  My only exposure to C++/CLI is a bridge between C# and .NET, and that's only recent exposure.

Comment: When I did something similar (a long time ago circa .Net 1.1) I had to write code that went against a Standard C dll. I found it easiest to write a C++/COM+ component to act as a wrapper rather than attempt to use `DllImport` in C#. A C++/CLI dll is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, gents.  I'll definiately be giving this a go at some point - though not having a c++ string to my bow, this could be an "interesting" exercise :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C# guy, not a C++ guy, but in the unmanaged C++ DLLs that I work with that use char* parameters I marshall them as StringBuilders.  I did read somewhere that for const char* the best choice is System.String but StringBuilder for char *.  However, if you need to keep the pointer so you can send it back to release the memory maybe StringBuilder would work better since System.String is immutable?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Joel.  I tried this (very briefly) and the process just blew up.  Could have been any number of things wrong with the way I implemented it though.  When I get a little breathing space I'll have another crack at it.